# Apache2 log not displayed for rewrite module and no rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I've VPS in OVH and i developped website with j2ee and i associate apache with tomcat using mod_jk.

when i enter url http://ip_of_vps/myapp, i enter to website.

until now it's ok

now i add rewrite for access to website using only ip_of_vps without context (myapp), for this i'm using Rewrite in apache2.config like this :

```
<virtualhost *:80>
RewriteEngine On
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
RewriteRule ^/$  http://ip_of_vps/myapp/ [P,L]
</virtualhost>
```

And i change All AllowOverride in directory from none to All

when i try to access to http://ip_of_vps, i've apache2 home page.

what i've forgot ?

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 server, apache2, tomcat7.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, typically you would write

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    ReWriteRule your rule
</IfModule>
```

so, is mod_rewrite actually loaded?
    do you need your RewriteBase to be /myapp/ ?

my suggestion would be to put a .htaccess in your html root directory
with a rule like

RewriteRule ^myapp/(.*)$ $1 [L]

this way you wont need mod_proxy at all

hope this helps

Comment: yes, the rewrite module is enabled, i want to access to my website without /myapp

Comment: when i add RewriteBase /, i've this error : RewriteBase: only valid in per-directory config files

Comment: the L flag is not needed here its implied by the P flag which requires mod_proxy.   RewriteRule ^myapp/(.*)$ $1 might be a better idea

Comment: yes mybad RewriteBase is used in .htaccess files - i think it will default to / if you configure mod_rewrite in your apache2.config. will edit my OP with a suggested .htaccess